# Вопрос про кеш в PHP

Tags: php, кэширование

3дpaствyйте, я пишу что-то вроде форума, и у меня возник вопрос.

Большая часть запросов к базе данных уходит на проверку существования какого-то объекта, например пользователя с определенным id или username, я думаю, что это можно оптимизировать, сохраняя в кэше сервера наиболее часто используемые значения, например, id, username или token, мы не будем делать лишние запросы к БД, делая их к кэш-серверу, тем самым распределяя нагрузку между серверами.

Правилен ли этот подход? И какую систему кеширования лучше использовать на ваш взгляд?

Comment: "*сохраняя в кэше сервера наиболее часто используемые значения, например, id, username или token,*" --- два перепндикулярных высказывания в одном.....Да, верно, в кэш неплохо заносить часто используемые вещи, которые не часто меняются...........`id, username или token`  при этом не часто используемые вещи. Например юзер может зарегаться, посмотреть что-то и уйти на несколько лет. зачем его данные в кэше? А людей зарегистрировалось миллион, а используют тысяча. Зачем эти данные в кэше?

Comment: "*какую систему кеширования лучше использовать*" --- зависит от многих параметров. Так что это не конструктиный подход. Если хочется пощупать кэш - бери любой, хоть memcached, хоть redis (самые популярные),  xcache, hyperDex и пр.